# PHP mysqli_query reports syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

```
string(150) "
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT *, @row := @row +1 AS rownum 
        FROM (SELECT @row :=0) r, `coordinates` 
        WHERE fid='3'
    ) ranked 
    HAVING rownum % FLOOR(@row/20) = 1
" 

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

> Connect Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ' FROM (SELECT *, @row := @row +1 AS rownum FROM (SELECT @row
>   :=0) r, `coordina' at line 1

The first line is a var_dump of my `$sql` variable, but the sql works just fine from command line. It reports an error when using the PHP.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure myself, but perhaps you can try moving your FROM (SELECT.... into the same line.. meaning the query as in one line..

Comment: It is all one line, but some guy edited the formatting

Comment: Cannot reproduce, there is no syntax error.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT *, FROM`?

Comment: I see that `$sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, @row := @row +1 AS rownum FROM (SELECT @row :=0) r, coordinates WHERE fid='3') ranked HAVING rownum % FLOOR(@row/20) = 1"; var_dump($sql);` only shows `string(145)`. So where are there other `5` chars?

Comment: adding in the backticks, there are 2 more chars, giving string(147) the commented out does not work, the 147 length does work./*
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, @row := @row +1 AS rownum FROM (SELECT @row :=0) r, `$tbl_name` WHERE fid='$fid') ranked HAVING rownum % FLOOR(@row/$num_data_points) = 1";
*/
  $sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, @row := @row +1 AS rownum FROM (SELECT @row :=0) r, `coordinates` WHERE fid='3') ranked HAVING rownum % FLOOR(@row/20) = 1";

Answer (score 0):

This is just so weird, sorry that I do not know what the issue is but the $sql that is not commented out does not work and has string (150), but the $sql that is commented out works and is string (147), the editor is coda 2 on mac, and there are no spaces between "ranked" and "HAVING"

[image: error]